# Why does initscr() after a delwin() return undef?

Tags: ncurses, raku

Why does the `delwin` cause the second `initscr` to return nothing? I thought the `endwin` would reset to the state as it was before calling `initscr`.

```
use NCurses;

my $win = initscr();
addstr( 'AAA' );
nc_refresh();
sleep 2;
delwin( $win );
endwin();

...

my $new_win = initscr();
if ! $new_win.defined {
    endwin();
    dd $new_win;            # NCurses::WINDOW $new_win = NCurses::WINDOW
    die "win undefined";    # win undefined
}
addstr( 'BBB' );
nc_refresh();
sleep 2;
delwin( $new_win );
endwin;
```

Comment: What does `dd $new_win` say?  Perhaps a `Failure` was returned?

Comment: I updated the example.

Comment: `endwin` only suspends (for lack of a better term) the curses interface, and does not free any resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's actually happening is that `initscr` returns **`stdscr`** (the standard window).  The `delwin` deleted it (and the pointer is part of a **`SCREEN`** structure which is duly updated), so a subsequent call to `initscr` (not having created a new **screen** with `newterm`) will return that **`NULL`** pointer.  In principle, an application could reference **`curscr`** and **`newscr`** (two other windows created during initialization), but the Perl interface likely ignores those.

It helps to read the documentation however.  Quoting the [*Differences*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Differences) section of the `initscr` manual page:

> **Differences**
>
> X/Open  specifies that portable applications must not call **`initscr`** more
>          than once:
>
> - The portable way to use **`initscr`** is once only,  using  **`refresh`**  (see
>            curs_refresh(3x)) to restore the screen after endwin.
> - This implementation allows using **`initscr`** after **`endwin`**.
>
> Old versions of curses, e.g., BSD 4.4, may have returned a null pointer
>          from **`initscr`** when an error is detected, rather  than  exiting.   It  is
>          safe but redundant to check the return value of **`initscr`** in XSI Curses.